# How can I delete an app in Admob, or at least hide or rename it?

Tags: admob, hide, rename

I've seen this has been asked back in 2011, but since then have past 3 years and Admob moved to a whole new version, I hope some things have been fixed.

In the new Admob, in the Monetize section, I have created the apps and ads I needed and everything was ok, but lately I wanted to check what else I can do to personalize ads and ended up with 2 more apps that i want to delete, and one has the name identical to one of my best performing apps and I often confuse them. I want to delete, hide or at least rename them, but found no way. Wanted to contact support through Help, but found no way.

My Admob apps list is messed up and very frustrating! Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Here a little tutorial how to hide an app. It is in a foreign language but you'll figure it out.

In the top right corner next to your account name. Click on the *preferences* symbol and from the drop down menu choose `Manage Applications`:

[image: preferences -> manage apps]

Now you see list of all your apps. Select the respective check box and click `Hide` on top of the list:

[image: select checkbox -> click hide]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know we can't delete an app from admob but we can hide them.
after hiding they won't be shown in monetize tab.

To do this just click on setting icon at top right corner.
Then click on app management tab.
then you will see all of your app. Just select the app which you want to hide by checking left box and click on Hide.

done. Now it will not irritate you :).