# can i link my app with different name in admob?

Tags: admob

i recently add a app in my admob account, now trying to delete, but did not find option to delete or rename the app from my admob account. i saw a related question on  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267440/how-can-i-delete-an-app-in-admob-or-at-least-hide-or-rename-it),

I think admob have't provide option to doing this(delete or rename).

i put my existing app(myapp) banner and Interstitial ad unit ID in my new app(which name is different), and publish on play store. now my question is

**1.can i link my new app(whose name is different on play store) to admob account**

or

**2.should i generate a new ad unit id for my new app from admob and republish on play store after changing ad unit ID**

If i do First thing then- can admob suspend my account or is it right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not delete the application. Only archived ads. Admob names in the console only for your convenience. You will not be blocked for this. I just advise you not to go out to one AddApp of different android packages

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is fine. You can link your new app to the existing ad unit IDs as long as you're using the ad unit IDs in that new app.

Once you link it, the app name in your admob console will be automatically updated and renamed to your new app provided the app is live in the play or app store. 
You, therefore need not worry about it.